# Correct place to store application serial in linux globaly, generated at initial start

Tags: c++, c, linux

Our software needs to generate a random serial key, when the software is started for the first time. This key should be used globally for the software on this system. It should also be reused if the software gets reinstalled or moved to another directory. Normally I would generate it in */etc/...* or */var/...*, but it is not clear if the first start of application is done by root, so maybe the software has no permission to put the file there.

Where should I put the file? Is it a good idea to generate it in */tmp/...*?

The software is written in C/C++ and the target os is linux in general.

Comment: Wouldn't it be easier to generate the serial number during installation? At that time, you can be sure that you have root permissions. `/tmp` is definitely a very bad idea, this directory might be emptied automatically when rebooting.

Comment: Yes, you are right. The problem is that many of our customers simply copy the software onto their devices without installing it. If /tmp gets emptied automatically, it would be really a bad idea to put it there...

Comment: Is it a problem for you to store the serial number in the user's home directory, e.g. `/home/username/.mygreatapp/serial.txt` ? This means that if there are several users of your application on one computer, each of them will have a different serial numbers, but maybe that does not hurt that much in practice. There are not that many places in a Linux system that a normal user can write to and every other user can read.

Comment: Yes, `/tmp` gets emptied at random times, via random means, that vary system to system. Obviously, given its name, you can't use it for anything persistent. And if your " customers simply copy the software onto their devices without installing it", then maybe the right solution would be for your app to show a "Yo, Homey! Don't do that!" error message the first time it starts, without a proper installation.

Comment: So how I understand you there are two options: 1. store the serial in the user directory and the customer should prefer to use this user to run the app or he gets a new serial, 2. the customer should not copy it and has to install it instead. Then I could use /etc to store the serial. Thank you.